# python 2.7.6 to 2.7.12 broke my script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, snmp

I'm working on a simple script to send data to an elasticsearch node, but after changing my python version the script no longer runs.  It says the error is on line 6, but I have no idea why.  I've tried adding a comma after the 'yes', but it had no effect.  I've tried moving my braces and parenthesis down and it had to effect.  (I'm leaving out the import and other defined variables for brevity)

```
if "Temporary failure in name resolution" or "Timeout" in output:
            es.index(index='data', doc_type='data', body={
            'macs' : '',
            'data' : line,
            'date' : datetime.now(),
            'down' : 'yes' })
```

Here are the errors:

```
    snmpwalk: Timeout

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
    'down' : 'yes' })
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 279, in index
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 105, in perform_request
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2507668090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2507668090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

Thanks

Comment: `if "Temporary failure in name resolution" or "Timeout" in output` isn't doing what you think it does btw... It should be `if "Temporary failure in name resolution" in output or "Timeout" in output`

Comment: Also - is `es` a different instance of the server - seems a bit odd trying to log a failure to the same instance that's failed... And if it's not the same instance - maybe that one is also down - hence the error? Changing Python versions would have had no effect on this.

Comment: The script snmp walks a device to see if it's down.  The script is suppose to detect down devices and log it to ES.  The second part of the script is suppose to walk the device and then log information if its up and that part of the script gives the same error at the same location; the last line as well.

Comment: That's nice - but how can anyone tell that from the code you've posted? Changing Python versions would have had nothing to do with the error you're receiving... the error says you can't connect to the server - so the thing to solve is "why can't it?"

Comment: It was a network issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This could either be a network issue or mmapfs directory for elastic search has maxed out.

Try running the following to restart your network server

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If it does not work, then change your mmap count by running this command

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Reference
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html